# how to declare a variable with two types via typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to declare a variable with two types via ts.But the complier tips error.
like this:

```js
interface IAnyPropObject { 
    [name: string]: any;
}
let a: IAnyPropObject | ((str: string) => any);
a.B = "bbbbbbbb";//tips error
a("");//tips error
```

note:I don't want to use 'any' to declare.I just want to constraint the variable by this way only.Because of the code are so old and they are not TS code.

Comment: A variable with **two** types..? **Two**?! So, what your saying is, that in TypeScript a variable can be a String and an Integer at the same time. How is this even possible? **THIS IS MADNESS**!

Comment: TS supports union type.I just want to constraint the variable by this way.

Comment: Sure that code should throw an error, you didn't initialise `a` so you cannot assign a property on it.

Comment: @rudy It's not male and female at the same time, it's saying it can accept both types, but it's only one at a time.

Comment: @Bergi OP is talking about a compilation error, not a runtime. Dies TypeScript fail compilation for using uninitialized variables? Haven't tested it

Comment: @JuanMendes I have no idea, but I would have expected it to catch things like that.

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20c%3B%0D%0Ac.t%20%3D%203%3B

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Brief explanation of Mixin vs Union types.

Union: Either `this` or `that` type, but not both.

```
interface A { [name: string]: any; }
interface B { (str: string): string; }
type UnionType = A | B;
```

Mixin: A mix of `this` and `that` type at the same time.

```
interface A { [name: string]: any; }
interface B { (str: string): string; }
type MixinType = A & B;
```

Your code would work if you use a Mixin type, if that is your intention. Variable `a` can have a mix of both types at the same time.

Comment: To use the  &, the OP would have to pass something that is of both types,that is,  satisfies both interfaces;   in this case,  a function is an object so it would  be almost true except that you  can set a function property by brackets using a number,  which shouldn't be allowed from the definition given by the OP. What kind of object could you possibly pass in that correctly implements both interfaces?

Comment: yeah.I can leave out 'if ...'

Answer (score 6):

If you use an OR type, that doesn't mean your object has two types at the same time, you have to test it and use the correct type with casting inside of the test.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

```
interface IAnyPropObject { [name: string]: any; }
type MyFunc = (str: string) => any;
let a: IAnyPropObject | ((str: string) => any);
if (a instanceof Function) {
     (<MyFunc>a)("hi"); //passing a number will throw an error
} else {
    (<IAnyPropObject>a).b = 'bbbbbbbb';
}
```

You could also create a custom type guard, it's explained in the documentation I linked to, then you would not have to cast it. There's a lot more to be said, I just scratched the surface since I'm answering from my phone, read the doc for all the details.